# Powerpoint moves my objects alignment

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Using Office 2016.

When I copy/paste or move around ppt objects their alignment will go off by a pixel or two. Also happens when I resize the Powerpoint app window.

--- Before: [image]

----- After: [image]

See the middle grey object has shifted itself a pixel to the left hand side.

I noticed that since many years and many versions ago, but now because I am using ppt more heavily it starts to feel annoying, is there a way to fix/avoid this issue?

Comment: Check your grid and snap to grid options.

Comment: It might be that the grid snap is forcing the shape to a slightly incorrect location, so turning it off might help.  Or it may just be a display issue: if the left positions of the shapes are not exactly identical numerically, PPT may be rounding the left value up a pixel for one shape and down a pixel for another.  Zoom way in to see if the problem goes away.  Or just make sure it's fixed by selecting the shapes and using Format | Arrange | Align.